# Is there a regexp for all capital letters for the .contains method?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner to Java, I'm trying to write code that will see if there is a capital letter ANYWHERE in a string via the `.contains()` method.

Is there a valid way to say something like `string.contains((all capital letters));` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.contains` doesn't accept a regular expression. It expects a substring, wich is plain string or another `CharSequence`.

If you want to check that a string contains a capital letter, you can use a regex, as in the following example:

```
boolean containsUppercase = text.matches("^.*[A-Z].*$")
```

That will return `true` if a capital letter is found anywhere in the text.

Comment: So the text.matches("^.*[A-Z].*$") part goes through the string to see if there is at least one capital letter?

Comment: @BokChoy That's right. That regular expression roughly means "a string that contains any character between `A` and `Z`, and that's all the uppercase letters.

Comment: Okay thank you so much, and one more question if you don't mind, is there a regex for only lowercase letters?

Comment: @BokChoy As you can guess, using `text.matches("^.*[a-z].*$")` will match on lowercase letters. A good place to find this info is the documentation of the `Pattern` class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's from the [javadoc for Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
\p{javaLowerCase}   Equivalent to java.lang.Character.isLowerCase()
\p{javaUpperCase}   Equivalent to java.lang.Character.isUpperCase()
```

Here's an example:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(args[0].matches(".*\\p{javaUpperCase}.*"));
    }
}
```

Here's how it works:

```
$ javac Test.java
$ java Test "hello world"
false

$ java Test "capital F"
true
```

Unlike `[A-Z]` and variations, this works for all capital letters in all languages:

```
$ java Test 'Σ'  # Greek
true

$ java Test 'Å'  # Norwegian
true

$ java Test 'Я'  # Russian
true
```